# DS1307 on Beaglebone black

Tags: linux, i2c, beagleboneblack, real-time-clock

I am trying to integrate DS1307 RTC on beaglebone black, in which I am building a custom kernel with rootfs, I used SCL and SDA pins of beagle P9.17 & P9.18 ie; I2C-1 on beaglebone black but when I try to do

> i2cdetect -r 1

it doesn't shows 0x68 slave address of DS1307 as per the tutorials http://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-beaglebone-black/wiring-the-rtc

Any ideas about the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In beagle bone black there are 3 i2c's, i2c-0,1,2

And out of this you're using i2c-1, So according to the linux images of beaglebone black the i2c-0 may appear as i2c-1 and i2c-1 appear as i2c-2 and so on , So I suggest you that instead of using i2cdetect -r 1
try

> i2cdetect -r 2

so it might show the slave address you're looking for .... 0x68

And don't forget to add the DS1307 driver for the RTC in the kernel you're building if you're using a custom kernel